# TestFlight update of Flutter app updates only after reinstalling

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I face the following issue on a new update of my Flutter app on TestFlight that **each user needs to reinstall the app**, so that the user sees the new changes.

So it seems like if the user didn't delete the cache he doesn't see the new changes of the update.
However if the user updates the app and then reinstalled the app he sees all the new changes of my Flutter app.

What do I need to do so that the user doesn't need to delete and reinstall the app to also see the new changes of my Flutter app update?

Comment: why you don't have that functionality in an update to modify previously-stored cache ..?

Comment: @ShaileshBhokare  how can I modify the previously-stored cache? And why is it causing an issue?